# Thought-provoking functional computation problem

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

I have been assigned a very thought-provoking functional computation problem (to be completed $without$ a calculator) which has left me essentially stumped—that is, I really can't come up with an efficient method of solving this problem without simply plugging in attractive values.

The question is as follows: If $f(n+1) = n(-1)^{n+1}- 2f(n)$ for integral $n>1$, and $f(1)=f(1986)$, compute $$f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(1985).$$ Many thanks for any words of advice or hints.

Comment: This is a system of 1985 linear equations in 1985 variables with a special bidiagonal (plus one wrap around) structure.  This is trivial to solve with a computer.  You should be able to take advantage of the special structure of the system of equations to solve it by hand.

Comment: My question pertains to how I should approach the problem without the aid of a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $S = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{1985}f(k)$. Then, since $f(1) = f(1986)$, we have:

$S = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{1985}f(k)$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 2}^{1986}f(k)$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}f(n+1)$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}\left(n(-1)^{n+1} - 2f(n)\right)$

$= \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}n(-1)^{n+1}\right) - 2\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}f(n)\right)$ $= \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}n(-1)^{n+1}\right) - 2S$.

Therefore, $3S = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{1985}n(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: ^The more standard approach would have been to first show that $f(n) = C(-2)^n-(n+1)(-1)^n$ for some constant $C$, and then use the condition $f(1) = f(1986)$ to solve for $C$. However, that would have been more tedious.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks for the alternate perspective (+1). Unfortunately, my hand likely would break by the end of that method.

Comment: This is very clever.  A more pedestrian approach is to note that for $n$ even, you have $f(n+2)=2n+1+4f(n)$ and for $n$ odd you have $f(n+2)=-(2n+1)+4f(n)$.  Now define $g(n)=f(n)+an+b$ and find $a,b$ so that the recurrence is homogeneous.